# Does the version of IE included with Windows Mobile 6.1 support "new tab" or "new window"?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.1

I'm developing a small web app using ASP.NET (VB). Does the Windows Mobile 6.1 browser support "new tab"? How about "new window"?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<img src="image/specs.jpg"
     style="cursor: hand;"
     title="Define Serial Number"
     onclick="javascript: window.open('dialog_window.aspx?p=request_line_specs.aspx&appid=<%=AppId.Text%>&linenum=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LineNum")%>&apptype=<%=AppType.Text%>&itemcode=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemCode")%>&t=Define Serials', 'scroll:no; status:no; address: no; dialogWidth: 700px; dialogHeight: 500px;')"
/>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know if this handheld support new tab or new window? I'm this handheld version is Windows Mobile 6.1 classic.

Comment: Does my edit capture your intent?

Comment: Hi @Michael, that code is working well in web browser in my machine and also in my iPhone. How ever, when I'm trying that in my Windows Mobile. It doesn't open in a new windows nor tab. I'm asking, if the windows mobile 6.1 classic support that function which is **window.open**.

Comment: The *very first* search result for "Windows Mobile IE window.open" I get is http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonlan/archive/2006/09/20/761986.aspx, which mentions "When window.open is allowed to work, it will load content in the same window because IE Mobile does not support multiple windows." Did you do any searches yourself? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Internet Explorer that came with the Windows Mobile platforms does NOT support tab browsing.

Tab browsing came out around IE 8, and Widows Mobile includes a cut down version of ...IE6, I believe.

So, basically, tab browsing was not developed yet.

To my knowledge, the cut down version of IE in Windows Mobile will not support opening a link in a new window, either.

Hope this answers your question.